# Why drupal send modernizr js with MIME type text/js

Tags: javascript, drupal, mime-types, drupal-8

I have a problem with my drupal site. JavaScript fail because server constantly serve modernizr.min.js?v=3.3.1 file with content type text/js. In chrome appears error Refused to execute script from http://mysite/modernizr.min.js?v=3.3.1 because its MIME type ('text/js') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

This response for that file looks like

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=1209600
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:2110
Content-Type:text/js
Date:Wed, 14 Sep 2016 08:32:15 GMT
ETag:"bbc03e5-1248-53befc0d59a80"
Expires:Wed, 28 Sep 2016 08:32:15 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=1, max=100
Last-Modified:Wed, 07 Sep 2016 19:16:42 GMT
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
```

I setup drupal 8 on centos with php 7 and apache.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Problem is only on chrome, but I removed nosnif header from .htaccess and now is ok. But I am still confused why drupal serve only that file with Content-Type:text/js. Server is centos 6, php7 apache2 hosting is time4vps